# R: predict the type of csv file without reading entire contents

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I need to read a csv file and process the file contents according to the file type, whether it is a comma separated file or tab separated file.
I am using the following code, but it is inefficient, because if the input file is a comma separated file, I need to read the file twice.
The code i used is as follows:

```
readFile <- function(fileName){
  portData <- read.csv(fileName,sep="\t")
  if(length(portData) == 1){
    print("comma separated file")
    executeCommaSepFile(fileName)
  }
  else{
    print("tab separated file")
    #code to process the tab separated file
  }
}
executeCommaSepFile <- function(fileName){
  csvData <- read.csv(file=fileName, colClasses=c(NA, NA,"NULL",NA,"NULL",NA,"NULL","NULL","NULL"))
  #code to process the comma separated file
}
```

Is it possible to predict the type of file without reading the entire contents of the file? or if i pass the `portData` instead of `fileName`, i get the data inside `executeCommaSepFile()` in this format:

```
   RUS1000.01.29.1999.21st.Centy.Ins.Group.TW.Z.90130N10.72096.1527.534.0.01.21.188
1           RUS1000,01/29/1999,3com Corp,COMS,88553510,358764,16861.908,0.16,47.000
2                RUS1000,01/29/1999,3m Co,MMM,88579Y10,401346,31154.482,0.29,77.625
3 RUS1000,01/29/1999,A D C Telecommunicat,ADCT,00088630,135114,5379.226,0.05,39.813
4         RUS1000,01/29/1999,Abbott Labs,ABT,00282410,1517621,70474.523,0.66,46.438
```

Is this can be converted to the format of `read.csv(file=fileName, colClasses=c(NA, NA,"NULL",NA,"NULL",NA,"NULL","NULL","NULL")`) ?
ie, to this format:

```
   RUS1000 X01.29.1999 TW.Z  X72096
1  RUS1000  01/29/1999 COMS  358764
2  RUS1000  01/29/1999  MMM  401346
3  RUS1000  01/29/1999 ADCT  135114
4  RUS1000  01/29/1999  ABT 1517621
```

Comment: In the general case there is no way to tell what the separator is, since the elements of an arbitrary array could contain arbitrary characters.  If you have high faith that your csv and tsv files are well-behaved, perhaps using `readLines` to get a couple lines, and using `grep` to see if there are commas or tabs, will do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
portData <- read.csv(fileName,sep="\t")
if(length(portData) == 1) {
    print("comma separated file")
    dat <- read.csv(textConnection(portData))
    executeCommaSepFile(dat)  # pass the data frame, not the filename
}
else {
    print("tab separated file")
    #code to process the tab separated file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If staying with base R, you have at least two options.

Read in a small segment of the file (`nrows` argument to `read.table` and friends):

```
portData <- read.csv(fileName,sep="\t", nrows=1)
if(length(portData) == 1) {
    print("comma separated file")
    executeCommaSepFile(fileName)
}
else {
    print("tab separated file")
    executeTabSepFile(fileName) # run read.table in here
}
```

Read in the whole file, and if it didn't work, use `textConnection` to avoid going back to the disk (not efficient, but it works):

```
portData <- read.csv(fileName,sep="\t")
if(length(portData) == 1) {
    print("comma separated file")
    dat <- read.csv(textConnection(portData))
    executeCommaSepFile(dat)  # pass the data frame, not the filename
}
else {
    print("tab separated file")
    #code to process the tab separated file
}
```